# Cost management supplier Id

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have two questions regarding cost management API

1. According to the [Get payment endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/cost-payments-GET/), companyId returns "The ID of a supplier company. This is the ID of a company managed by BIM 360 Admin.", the issue it returns a numeric value such as **23845621** while the [Get companies endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/companies-GET/) returns GUID. How can I get the company info using the numeric value?
2. How can I get/edit tax info for payments using forge API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For company id, there are 2 different values,

- GUID value, which is an account level company ID, and not related to any project, you can get it by the endpoint https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/companies-GET/.
- Numeric value such as 23845621 from your description, this is actually a project company id, which you can get by the endpoint https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-companies-GET/, and the **member_group_id** is the property name, you can use this id to communicate with Cost.

About the tax info from payment, this is not exposed by API yet, I will talk to you separately about this request.